# Git-ing a branch from GitHub

Tags: git, github

I want to clone this `edge` branch of a github repo.

The following command is identically listed in the readme for both `master` and `edge`

`git clone --depth 1 git://github.com/bborn/communityengine.git vendor/plugins/community_engine`

How do I specify to git that I want the edge branch?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

just add a -b for branch

```
git clone --depth 1 git://github.com/bborn/communityengine.git vendor/plugins/community_engine -b edge
```

Then you'll have a folder called vendor/, and doing 'git branch' will show you the edge branch.